# Google Analytics behaviour flows multple interactions same page

Tags: google-analytics, analytics

I am looking at Google Analytics behaviour flows report and can see multiple interactions for the same page name some are on the same column and some are on different columns but with traffic flowing between. What are the reasons for this to happen? The only one I can think of is different query strings though these aren't being shown. Are there others?

[image: Multiple flows and interactions for a single page]

Comment: Hi! Are you referring to the two instances of "reports" in the second column, or something involving both columns and/or the numbers displayed?

Comment: Both. I have multiples on the same column and multiple columns.

Comment: Some people visit "reports" as their first step and some people visit it as their second step.   I don't see any traffic flowing from "reports" in the first column to "reports" in the second column.   In the second column you also have a separate reports URL that doesn't have the trailing slash.   If that is the same page, you should probably redirect that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Behavior Flow report is about the path taken through the site during sessions in your date range. The columns correspond to first page, second page, etc. You should expect to see duplication of pages in different columns because not everyone will visit a given page at the same point in their session.

The duplication you are seeing **within** the second column is due to your site allowing both `/reports/` and `/reports` as URLs. If these are actually the same page, it would be good to standardize, as Stephen Ostermiller advises in his comment. Since it appears there are other pages in that directory, `/reports/` is the better one to allow (that is, force `/reports` to add a trailing slash). That way your Behavior > Site Content > Content Drilldown report will work properly.

Here is how to read your screenshot:

- The most common page people land on when they visit the site is `/login.php`; the second most common is `/reports/`.
- About half the people who land on `/login.php` depart without visiting another page (the red part of the flow chart). Most of those who do not leave go to `/reports/` as the second page of their session.
- Most people who land on `/reports/` next visit to a page that's shown below the bottom of the screenshot. A significant percentage, however, go to `/reports` - via a form submit or link click that loads the page without the slash, I would assume, but that requires investigation.

You'll note no one goes from `/reports/` in the first column to `/reports/` in the second column; the Behavior Flow only shows movement between distinct pages. The duplication in the second column is because GA only knows one page is the same as the other by the URLs matching.